# A new theorem (discovered in 2013) equivalent to Brianchon theorem (the old theorem) discovered in XIX century?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, projective-geometry, plane-geometry, conic-sections

In 2013, I found a new problem as follows: Let six points $A_1$, $A_2$, ...$A_6$ lie on a circle $(O_1)$,  and the six points $B_1$, $B_2$,...,$B_6$  lie on another circle $(O_2)$. If the quadruples $A_i$, $A_{i+1}$, $B_{i+1}$, $B_i$ lie on a circles  with centers $C_i$  for $i=1,2,...,5$ then $A_6$, $A_1$, $B_1$, $B_6$ lie on a circle (namely center of the new circle is $C_6$) and $C_1C_4$, $C_2C_5$, $C_3C_6$ are concurrent.

[image]

The proof [3][4] show that the hexagon $C_1C_2C_3C_4C_5C_6$ circumscribed around a conic section with two Focus are $O_1$, $O_2$

The Theorem was re-discovered by Szilasis in 2017 (see [5])

**Converse of theorem:** Let a hexagon $C_1C_2C_3C_4C_5C_6$ which $C_1C_4, C_2C_5, C_3C_6$ are concurrent then exist many configuration of eight circles as figuration above.

If the converse theorem is true, so the theorem is equivalent with an old [theorem due to Brianchon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brianchon%27s_theorem)

**Special case:** Let a hexagon $C_1C_2C_3C_4C_5C_6$ circumscribed a conic with two focus $O_1$, $O_2$. Draw six circles $(C_1)$, $(C_2)$,....,$(C_6)$ with centers $C_1$, $C_2$,...$C_6$ and radii $C_1O_1$, $C_2O_1$, ...., $C_6O_1$ respectively. Let circles $(C_i)$ meets circle $(C_{i+1})$ again at $A_i$ then six points $A_1, A_2,..., A_6$ lie on a circle, namely circle $(A)$. Similarly:  Draw six circles $(C_1)$,$(C_2)$,....,$(C_6)$ with centers $C_1$, $C_2$,...$C_6$ and radii $C_1O_2$, $C_2O_2$, ...., $C_6O_2$ respectively. Let circles $(C_i)$ meets circle $(C_{i+1})$ again at $B_i$ then six points $B_1, B_2,..., B_6$ lie on a circle, namely the circle $(B)$.

> **Question 1:** Is the converse of theorem true?

> **Question 2:** How can one prove the radius of circle $(A)$ is equal to the radius of circle $(B)$?

[image]

**The dual of theorem on the ball creat a beautifull basket (see theorem dual in [8])**

[image]

**Some relation problem**

[Dao's theorem on six circumcenters](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/234053/daos-theorem-on-six-circumcenters-associated-with-a-cyclic-hexagon)

[Some Problems On Apollonian Gasket](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/318789/some-problems-on-apollonian-gasket)

[Can generalization of a generalization Pascal theorem, Pappus theorem to Higher Dimensions?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/272520/can-generalization-of-a-generalization-pascal-theorem-pappus-theorem-to-higher)

[A chain of six circles associated with six points on a circle (in Mobius plane)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/235181/a-chain-of-six-circles-associated-with-six-points-on-a-circle-in-mobius-plane)

[$N$-$th$ closed chain of six circles](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/304225/n-th-closed-chain-of-six-circles)

**Reference:**

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGxdv.png) - [Dao, O.T.: Problem 3845, Crux Mathematicorum, 39, Issue May 2013](https://cms.math.ca/publications/crux/issue/?volume=39&issue=5)

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bs97z.png)-https://www.geogebra.org/material/show/id/Zk3F5y5X

[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1NCS.png) - [J. Chris Fisher, Problem 3945, Crux Mathematicorum, Volume 40, Issue May, 2014](https://cms.math.ca/publications/crux/issue/?volume=40&issue=5)

[4]-[Michel Bataille, Solution to Problem 3945, Crux Mathematicorum, Volume 41, Issue May, 2015](https://cms.math.ca/publications/crux/issue/?volume=41&issue=5)

[5]-[Gábor Gévay, A remarkable theorem on eight circles, Forum Geométrico rum, Volume 18 (2018), 401--408](http://forumgeom.fau.edu/FG2018volume18/FG201845.pdf)

[6]-[Ákos G.Horváth, A note on the centers of a closed chain of circles](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1804.10345.pdf)

[7]-[Dao Thanh Oai, The Nine Circles Problem and the Sixteen Points Circle, International Journal of Computer Discovered Mathematics ISSN 2367-7775, June 2016, Volume 1, No.2, pp. 21-24.](http://www.journal-1.eu/2016-2/Dao-Thanh-Oai-sixteen-points-pp.21-24.pdf)

[8]-[Dao Thanh Oai, Cherng-Tiao Perng, On The Eight Circles Theorem and Its Dual, International Journal of Geometry, Vol. 8 (2019), no. 2, page 49-53](https://ijgeometry.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/49-53.pdf)

Comment: Thanks Dr @David Roberts

Comment: I checked the converse theorem by computer, the converse is true. But I am looking for a proof.